# FQL query for getting the details of users with a particular appid

Tags: facebook, visual-studio-2008, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I need a code sample to get the userid,name,profile pic of users who have approved my app using my appid. What will be the output of that fql ? json or xml? I am using vs2008 and c# frame work 3.5. Can u please tell me which version of facebook.dll is compatible with c# 2008 .I tried my query sample with facebook c# sdk version 5.2.1.0 .

when i declare fb object it give me an error microsoft.contracts could not be loaded....

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();//  file not found exception occured here.

        var fbApp = new FacebookClient();
        var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fbApp.Get("me");
        var name = (string)result["name"];
```

is the issue with framework version 3.5 ? i downloaded the latest version of 6.0.5 c#sdk source code but it is targetted to vs2010. So can u please suggest a solution so that i can use fql code in my c# 2008 app? Thanks in advance. I believe i presented the qn neatly...

Answer (score 0):

Starting from v6, binaries will only be distributed using nuget.

Since nuget package manager is not supported in vs2008, you will need to use the nuget command line. nuget.exe

You can download v6 using

```
nuget install facebook -pre
```

Then reference the dll from `net35-client` folder